# Redirect URLs with Apache

Tags: apache, url, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I get Apache to automatically redirect URLs such as:

mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=about_me
mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=contact
etc.

to:

mydomain.com/about_me
mydomain.com/contact

Also, mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=home_page should redirect to simply: mydomain.com/

Right now, I have on my .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ webpage.php?name=home_page [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ webpage.php?name=$1 [L]

But the RewriteRule doesn't redirect my visitors automatically, it simply lets them use either the short or long URL. In other words, I want to force the short URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^webpage.php?name=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ webpage.php?name=home_page [L] 
RewriteRule (.*)/$ webpage.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Linuxios, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't automatically take me to the short URL.

Comment: @gts-joe: What URL did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify. Do you want apache to work like this:

Visitor goes to "mydomain.com/about_me", and "mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=about_me" is presented.
Visitor goes to "mydomain.com/contact", and "mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=contact" is presented.

If you want to have this. You should try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webpage.php?name=$1 [L]
```

If you want "mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=about_me" to automatically redirect to "mydomain.com/about_me". You should add extra checks in the webpage.php file. The checks should evaluate the URI to see if "webpage.php" is used, if it did, then it should redirect to the short URL by using the "header" function. So here is the code:

```
$page="webpage.php";

if(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,strlen($page)) == $page) {
  $location = "Location: http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/".$_GET["name"];
  header($location);
} 
// whatever webpage.php does.
```

Comment: leeroyc, that's what I have at the moment. But if the user goes to mydomain.com/webpage.php?name=about_me first, is there a way for the web browser's address bar to show mydomain.com/about_me/ instead? I want to force the short URL, even if the user types in the long one.